# How do I sort the x axis labels of my data frame by alphabetical order?

Tags: r, dataframe, sorting

Hi I'm a uni student (not studying programming or computer science, so I have minimal experience with R).

I've imported a .csv file into a data frame, containing the names of genes on the x-axis and tissue samples on the y-axis. As part of an assignment, I have a question asking me to write code that sorts the gene names alphabetically AND shows what the first 15 gene names would be. I'm marked on whether my code work and how concise/efficient it is. Could someone help me? I have attached a snippet of the dataframe for context. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Please provide a reprex

Comment: `sort(rownames(mydataframe))`

Comment: Hi, sorry I don't understand what you mean. What is a reprex?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Hi yes, I've got that far. But I need to write code that sorts the gene names alphabetically and shows ONLY the first 15 genes.

Comment: Could you use @Phil's suggestion, then get the first 15 rows like: `newdf <- df[ order(rownames(df)),]; new_newdf <- newdf[1:15,]`?

Comment: Or just run `sort(rownames(mydataframe))[1:15]`